# HQL Query adding JOINS for lazy associations

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have an entity 'Notifications' that has about 10 `ManyToOne` relations which are marked as `FetchType.Lazy` as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
```

However after constructing an HQL query that retrieves a list of Notifications (and does not include any of these relations) I look at the generated SQL it includes `LEFT OUTER JOIN`'s for all of these lazy associations

Why is hibernate including these when that should be lazy loaded?

(Hibernate 3.6 | Postgres)

UPDATE: HQL & SQL included:

```
public List<Notification> findUserNotifications(User user, int limit, int offset){

    String s = "from Notification as n ";
    s+="where (n.user = :user or n.pool = :pool or n.client = :client or n.admin is not null ";
    s+=") and n.dateCreated > :userStartDate ";
    s+="order by dateCreated desc";
    Query query = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(s);
    query.setParameter("user", user);
    query.setParameter("userStartDate", user.getDateCreated());
    query.setParameter("pool", user.getLocalPool());
    query.setParameter("client", user.getLocalPool().getClient());
    query.setFirstResult(offset);
    query.setMaxResults(limit);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Generated SQL:

```
select notificati0_.notification_id as notifica1_159_, notificati0_.admin_audience as admin7_159_, notificati0_.client_audience as client8_159_, notificati0_.client_tag_audience as client9_159_, notificati0_.custom_message as custom2_159_, notificati0_.date_created as date3_159_, notificati0_.icon as icon159_, notificati0_.message_id as message5_159_, notificati0_.pool_audience as pool10_159_, notificati0_.title_id as title6_159_, notificati0_.user_audience as user11_159_, notificati0_1_.client_user_id as client1_160_, notificati0_2_.swim_mate_id as swim1_165_, notificati0_3_.user_training_plan_id as user1_169_, notificati0_4_.user_challenge_id as user1_167_, notificati0_4_.user_id as user2_167_, notificati0_5_.session_id as session1_164_, notificati0_6_.personal_best_id as personal1_163_, notificati0_7_.competition_user_session_id as competit1_162_, notificati0_8_.user_challenge_id as user1_166_, notificati0_9_.competition_user_id as competit1_161_, notificati0_10_.user_drill_id as user1_168_ from public.notifications notificati0_ left outer join public.notification_client_user_creators notificati0_1_ on notificati0_.notification_id=notificati0_1_.notification_id left outer join public.swim_mate_notifications notificati0_2_ on notificati0_.notification_id=notificati0_2_.notification_id left outer join public.user_training_plan_notifications notificati0_3_ on notificati0_.notification_id=notificati0_3_.notification_id left outer join public.ucu_notifications notificati0_4_ on notificati0_.notification_id=notificati0_4_.notification_id left outer join public.session_notifications notificati0_5_ on notificati0_.notification_id=notificati0_5_.notification_id left outer join public.pb_notifications notificati0_6_ on notificati0_.notification_id=notificati0_6_.notification_id left outer join public.competition_session_notifications notificati0_7_ on notificati0_.notification_id=notificati0_7_.notification_id left outer join public.user_challenge_notifications notificati0_8_ on notificati0_.notification_id=notificati0_8_.notification_id left outer join public.competition_user_notifications notificati0_9_ on notificati0_.notification_id=notificati0_9_.notification_id left outer join public.user_drill_notifications notificati0_10_ on notificati0_.notification_id=notificati0_10_.notification_id where (notificati0_.user_audience=? or notificati0_.pool_audience=1 or notificati0_.client_audience=1 or notificati0_.admin_audience is not null) and notificati0_.date_created>? order by notificati0_.date_created desc limit ?
```

and the entity itself:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notifications", schema = "public")
public class Notification implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int notificationId;
    private User user;
    private String titleId;
    private String messageId;
    private String icon;
    private boolean customMessage;
    private Date dateCreated;

    //Relations
    private SwimMate swimMate;
    private Session session;
    private PersonalBest personalBest;
    private UserChallengeUser userChallengeUser;
    private UserChallenge userChallenge;
    private CompetitionUserSession competitionUserSession;
    private CompetitionUser competitionUser;
    private UserTrainingPlan userTrainingPlan;
    private DockActiveBand dockActiveBand;
    private UserDrill userDrill;
    private Pool pool;
    private Client client;
    private ClientTag clientTag;
    private Admin admin;
    private ClientUser clientUserCreator;

    public Notification() {
    }

    public Notification(User user, String titleId, String messageId, String icon) {
        super();
        this.user = user;
        this.titleId = titleId;
        this.messageId = messageId;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.dateCreated = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "notification_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getNotificationId() {
        return this.notificationId;
    }

    public void setNotificationId(int notificationId) {
        this.notificationId = notificationId;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_created", nullable = false, length = 29)
    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return this.dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    @Length(min=10,max=40)
    @Column(name = "title_id", nullable = false)
    public String getTitleId() {
        return titleId;
    }

    public void setTitleId(String titleId) {
        this.titleId = titleId;
    }

    @Column(name = "message_id", nullable = false)
    public String getMessageId() {
        return this.messageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    @Column(name = "icon", nullable = false)
    public String getIcon() {
        return this.icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    @Column(name = "custom_message", nullable = false)
    public boolean isCustomMessage() {
        return this.customMessage;
    }

    public void setCustomMessage(boolean customMessage) {
        this.customMessage = customMessage;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_audience", nullable = true)
    public User getUser(){
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pool_audience", nullable = true)
    public Pool getPool() {
        return pool;
    }

    public void setPool(Pool pool) {
        this.pool = pool;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_tag_audience", nullable = true)
    public ClientTag getClientTag() {
        return clientTag;
    }

    public void setClientTag(ClientTag clientTag) {
        this.clientTag = clientTag;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_audience", nullable = true)
    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "admin_audience", nullable = true)
    public Admin getAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(Admin admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "swim_mate_notifications", schema = "public", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "notification_id") }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "swim_mate_id") })
    public SwimMate getSwimMate() {
        return swimMate;
    }

    public void setSwimMate(SwimMate swimMate) {
        this.swimMate = swimMate;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "session_notifications", schema = "public", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "notification_id", nullable=true)}, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "session_id", nullable=true) })
    public Session getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    public void setSession(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "pb_notifications", schema = "public",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "notification_id", nullable=true) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "personal_best_id", nullable=true) })
    public PersonalBest getPersonalBest() {
        return personalBest;
    }

    public void setPersonalBest(PersonalBest personalBest) {
        this.personalBest = personalBest;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "ucu_notifications", schema = "public", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "notification_id") }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_challenge_id"), @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") })
    public UserChallengeUser getUserChallengeUser() {
        return userChallengeUser;
    }

    public void setUserChallengeUser(UserChallengeUser userChallengeUser) {
        this.userChallengeUser = userChallengeUser;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_challenge_notifications", schema = "public", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "notification_id") }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_challenge_id")})
    public UserChallenge getUserChallenge(){
        return userChallenge;
    }

    public void setUserChallenge(UserChallenge userChallenge) {
        this.userChallenge = userChallenge;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "competition_session_notifications", schema = "public", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "notification_id", nullable=true) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "competition_user_session_id", nullable=true)})
    public CompetitionUserSession getCompetitionUserSession() {
        return competitionUserSession;
    }

    public void setCompetitionUserSession(CompetitionUserSession competitionUserSession) {
        this.competitionUserSession = competitionUserSession;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "competition_user_notifications", schema = "public",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "notification_id") }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "competition_user_id")})
    public CompetitionUser getCompetitionUser() {
        return competitionUser;
    }

    public void setCompetitionUser(CompetitionUser competitionUser) {
        this.competitionUser = competitionUser;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_training_plan_notifications", schema = "public",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "notification_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_training_plan_id") })
    public UserTrainingPlan getUserTrainingPlan() {
        return userTrainingPlan;
    }

    public void setUserTrainingPlan(UserTrainingPlan userTrainingPlan) {
        this.userTrainingPlan = userTrainingPlan;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_drill_notifications", schema = "public", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "notification_id") }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_drill_id") })
    public UserDrill getUserDrill() {
        return userDrill;
    }

    public void setUserDrill(UserDrill userDrill) {
        this.userDrill = userDrill;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "notification", optional = true)
    public DockActiveBand getDockActiveBand() {
        return dockActiveBand;
    }

    public void setDockActiveBand(DockActiveBand dockActiveBand) {
        this.dockActiveBand = dockActiveBand;
    }

    //Log Creator Info

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "notification_client_user_creators", schema = "public",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "notification_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "client_user_id") })
    public ClientUser getClientUserCreator() {
        return clientUserCreator;
    }

    public void setClientUserCreator(ClientUser clientUserCreator) {
        this.clientUserCreator = clientUserCreator;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the code. Post the HQL query. Post the SQL query.

Comment: @JBNizet - Code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a join table to map your toOne association, instead of a join column (which is the default). Since the association is optional, Hibernate has no way to know, just by getting the columns of the main table, if there is an associated entity or not. With a join column, it can:

- if the column is null, then the ManyToOne-annotated field is null
- if the column is not null,  then the ManyToOne-annotated field is a lazy proxy containing the ID of the target entity

With a join table, Hibernate is forced to get the columns from the join table in order to decide if the field must be set to null or if it must be initialized with a proxy.